# The Last Ramadan of Prophet Muhammad (Part 2)

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, source-identification, seerah

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPAT5H3ze74), Wahaj Tarin mentions a dream of Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him), and he also recite the Qur'an twice. And then he realizing that, that will be the final Ramadan for him. Is the incident part of sahih hadith collection? If not, what is the most authentic source for that incident?

Comment: Do you mean to ask about all three things or one incident specifically?

Comment: I am asking whatever I can learn, after all, aren't all related to one another, and happened at the same time. [I am aware of this hadith though.](https://abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2019/04/11/ramadan-jibreel-quran-twice/)

Comment: @blackened this hadith and a statement from the sermon of the prophet's farewell hajj are the most authentic informations I know about. I never heard about a dream in this context.